# ExtJS 4 grid now showing after unhiding the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs, extjs4

I am using ExtJS 4 grid, and my requirement is that the grid should be hidden at the first and should be visible when a certain button is pressed. 
I dont know if it is a bug or anything, but the problem is that if set the `style="display:none;"` for the div on which im rendering the grid, and display it later on clicking a button, the grid does not show up. But instead if i show the grid first and the press the button for it to hide or display the grid, it works great.
 Here is the code HTML and Javascript.
HTML:

```
<div id="outPut">
    <div id="gridShowClick" style="height: 50px; 
    width: 180px; background-color:Black; color:White; 
    padding-top:25px; text-align:center;" >
                Press to show the grid

    </div>
</div>
<div id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none;" >
    <div id="exampleGrid" style="">

    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var grid;
    var colModel;
    Ext.onReady(function () {
        $("#gridShowClick").bind("click", showGridClick);
        colModel = [
            {
                header: "Field 1",
                menuDisabled: true,
                width: 120,
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                header: "Field 2",
                menuDisabled: true,
                width: 120,
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                header: "Field 3",
                menuDisabled: true,
                width: 120,
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                header: "Field 4",
                menuDisabled: true,
                width: 120,
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                header: "Field 5",
                menuDisabled: true,
                width: 120,
                sortable: false
            }
        ];
        grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            id: "exampleGridPanel",
            columns: colModel,
            columnLines: true,
            renderTo: "exampleGrid"
        });
    });
    function showGridClick() { $("#hiddenDiv").show(); }
```

Comment: I did something to work around for a time being, i set the `windows.setTimeout(hideDiv, 300);` so to show it for 300 ms and then hide it again. But i dont think this is such a good thing to do.

Comment: @rahul what difference does it make, if i do it like you or simply put a function name in it, like i did.

Comment: what is hideDiv in windows.setTimeout(hideDiv, 300);

Comment: as the name shows, it is a function which hides the div `function hideDiv(){$("#hiddenDiv").hide();}`

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <div id="exampleGrid"></div>

   grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        id: "exampleGridPanel",
        columns: colModel,
        columnLines: true,
        hidden: true //hidden 
        renderTo: "exampleGrid"
    });

    function showGridClick() {
        Ext.getCmp('exampleGridPanel').show();
    }
```

removed `<div id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none;" >`

should work

Comment: no problem, but the way it is done is not good IMHO ) design and structure should be more extendable, reliable and readable. Plus avoid IDs where it is possible. It can be treated as quick fix ;)